# (Linux, C/C++) Segmentation fault caused when manually assigning an address to a pointer

Tags: c++, c

I would like to make a memory reader for my school project for Linux OS but I've encountered an error. I've made this simple test code just to find out what causes it. And it turns out, that when I cast user's input (which is a hex value) to the pointer and then try to access it, segmentation fault happens. It worked well on Windows, the same exact code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int address = -1; //Address to input
    
    int value = 10; //Some value

    printf("Address of some value: %X\n",&value); //Print the address of "value" for user to input

    printf("INPUT:");
    scanf("%X",&address); //User inputs the address

    int* pointer = (int*)address; //Cast user's input to a pointer

    printf("Pointer points to: %X\n",pointer);
    printf("Value of pointer: %d\n",*pointer);
    
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the terminal output:

```
[drstahp@DrSTAHP test]$ sudo ./test
Address of some value: 1BA1245C
INPUT:1BA1245C
Pointer points to: 1BA1245C
Segmentation fault
[drstahp@DrSTAHP test]$ ^C
[drstahp@DrSTAHP test]$
```

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 the adress comes from the local variable

Comment: Are you in 32-bit environment or 64-bit environment?

Comment: Is the cause really user input? What happens when you use `address = (int)&value;` instead of `scanf("%X",&address);`?

Comment: There's the special format specifier %p for printing pointers. It could be that %X only prints the lower 32 bit of the adress. To store pointers, use the integer type uintptr_t.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Hi. Thanks for answer. The address I'm trying to access is my local variable, owned by the same process. The first printf() function prints the address for me to input, so it should be correct. If I type (int*)&address , the pointer will point at the address of variable "address" instead of it's value, which IS my desired address.

Comment: @MikeCAT 64 bit, Manjaro Linux. I'm going to try casting &value to an int, just like you've said.

Comment: An `int` is too short to hold an address. You need a variable of type `size_t` which is likely `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @DrSTAHP I read too quickly, I understand what is going on now. The solution for me was to change the first format specifier to %p and use `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Thank you. Int wasn't enough to store the address and printf() didn't print an entire address too, so that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
int address = -1;
```

An `int` may not be able to hold an entire address. In `<stdint.h>` there is a type called `intptr_t` that is guaranteed to be able to hold any pointer address. You should preferably use that.

```c
printf("Address of some value: %X\n",&value);
```

The complete address of `value` isn't printed. `printf` has a specific format specifier for printing an address: `%p`.

```c
scanf("%X",&address);
```

Now that `address` is an `intptr_t`, you have to change the format specifier to match its size. For me, `intptr_t` is defined as a `long`, so I have to change the format specifier to `%lX`. Alternatively (and perhaps the better solution), you could use the `SCNxPTR` macro for assigning a hex number to an `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t` that is guaranteed to be correct. In this case though, you will want to replace your `#include <stdint.h>` with `#include <inttypes.h>`.

The final program can look something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    intptr_t address = -1;
    int value = 10;

    printf("Address of some value: %p\n",&value);

    printf("INPUT:");
    scanf("%"SCNxPTR, &address);

    int* pointer = (int*)address;

    printf("Pointer points to: %p\n",pointer);
    printf("Value of pointer: %d\n",*pointer);
    
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here's an example of running it:

```
Address of some value: 0x7fff59c47abc
INPUT:7FFF59C47ABC
Pointer points to: 0x7fff59c47abc
Value of pointer: 10
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it works! It makes sense now, since int wasn't enough to store the address and printf() didn't print everything.

Comment: @DrSTAHP No problem. Sorry for misunderstanding the question in the beginning, but what ultimately must have happened in your program is likely what I expected, since the inputted address wasn't actually identical to the address of `value`, you probably tried to access some random part of memory you weren't supposed to, hence SIGSEGV.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 wouldn't intptr_t be more appropriate?

Comment: @AngusComber I suppose you're right, I just chose to use `uintptr_t` out of some (definitely unwarranted now that I think of it) paranoia. `intptr_t` would definitely be appropriate especially since OP chooses to set the initial value to -1 (I initially removed this but added it back in an edit). Apart from that, the program runs the same.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I guess a pointer will always be a positive number so probably you are right thinking about it as used in this example.  intptr_t is probably useful if you want to get the difference between 2 pointers.